# How to use BLAS functions in Fortran mex files

Tags: matlab, fortran, mex, blas

I've tried to use BLAS functions in my Fortran mex file, but it didn't work. Here's an example of one of my code that uses DGEMM:

```
#include "fintrf.h"

C     Gateway subroutine
  subroutine mexfunction(nlhs, plhs, nrhs, prhs)

C     Declarations
  implicit none

C     mexFunction arguments:
  mwPointer plhs(*), prhs(*)
  integer nlhs, nrhs

C     Function declarations:
  mwPointer mxGetPr
  mwPointer mxCreateDoubleMatrix
  mwsize    mxGetM,mxGetN

C     Pointers to input/output mxArrays:
  mwPointer pr_A, pr_B, pr_C
  mwSize :: sizea,sizeb

C     Array information:

  real*8, allocatable :: A(:,:),B(:,:),C(:,:)

C     Get the size of the input array.
  sizea = mxGetM(prhs(1))
  sizeb = mxGetN(prhs(2))

  allocate(A(sizea,sizea),B(sizea,sizeb),C(sizea,sizeb))

C     Create Fortran array from the input argument.
  pr_A = mxGetPr(prhs(1))
  pr_B = mxGetPr(prhs(2))

  call mxCopyPtrToReal8( pr_A, A, sizea**2 )
  call mxCopyPtrToReal8( pr_B, B, sizea*sizeb )

  call MUL(A,B,C,sizea,sizeb)

C     Create matrix for the return argument.
  plhs(1) = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(sizea, sizeb, 0)

  pr_C = mxGetPr(plhs(1))

  call mxCopyReal8ToPtr(C , pr_C, sizea*sizeb )

  return
  end

  subroutine MUL(A,B,C,sizea,sizeb)

  implicit none

  mwSize :: sizea,sizeb
  real*8 :: A(sizea,sizea),B(sizea,sizeb),C(sizea,sizeb),alpha,beta
  integer*4 :: M,N,K
  character ch1, ch2

  ch1 = 'N'
  ch2 = 'N'
  M=size(A,1)
  N=size(B,2)
  K=size(A,2)
  Alpha=1.
  Beta=0.

  CALL DGEMM(ch1,ch2,M,N,K,ALPHA,A,M,B,K,BETA,C,M)


  return
  end subroutine MUL
```

I use the following line to create a mex file:

```
mex -lmwblas Test.F
```

The mex file builds without any error, but when I try to use the function, matlab closes without any error message.  I'm using Matlab R2016a with *Intel Visual Fortran Composer XE 2013* with *Microsoft Visual Studio 2012*.

Comment: If you comment out the DGEMM call, does it run without crashing?

Comment: @Vladimir F it runs and returns zero vector

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here's the solution:

```
#include "fintrf.h"

C     Gateway subroutine
  subroutine mexfunction(nlhs, plhs, nrhs, prhs)

C     Declarations
  implicit none

C     mexFunction arguments:
  mwPointer plhs(*), prhs(*)
  integer nlhs, nrhs

C     Function declarations:
  mwPointer mxGetPr
  mwPointer mxCreateDoubleMatrix
  mwsize    mxGetM,mxGetN

C     Pointers to input/output mxArrays:
  mwPointer pr_A, pr_B, pr_C
  mwSignedIndex :: sizea,sizeb

C     Array information:

  real*8, allocatable :: A(:,:),B(:,:),C(:,:)

C     Get the size of the input array.
  sizea = mxGetM(prhs(1))
  sizeb = mxGetN(prhs(2))

  allocate(A(sizea,sizea),B(sizea,sizeb),C(sizea,sizeb))

C     Create Fortran array from the input argument.
  pr_A = mxGetPr(prhs(1))
  pr_B = mxGetPr(prhs(2))

  call mxCopyPtrToReal8( pr_A, A, sizea**2 )
  call mxCopyPtrToReal8( pr_B, B, sizea*sizeb )

  call MUL(A,B,C,sizea,sizeb)

C     Create matrix for the return argument.
  plhs(1) = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(sizea, sizeb, 0)

  pr_C = mxGetPr(plhs(1))

  call mxCopyReal8ToPtr(C , pr_C, sizea*sizeb )

  return
  end

  subroutine MUL(A,B,C,sizea,sizeb)

  implicit none

  mwSignedIndex :: sizea,sizeb
  real*8 :: A(sizea,sizea),B(sizea,sizeb),C(sizea,sizeb),alpha,beta
  mwSignedIndex :: M,N,K
  character ch1, ch2

  ch1 = 'N'
  ch2 = 'N'
  M=size(A,1)
  N=size(B,2)
  K=size(A,2)
  Alpha=1.0
  Beta=0.0
  CALL DGEMM(ch1,ch2,M,N,K,ALPHA,A,M,B,K,BETA,C,M)


  return
  end subroutine MUL
```

and to build the mex file use

```
mex -largeArrayDims -lmwblas Test.F
```

Comment: If you want this to be useful to others it would be worth to say at least what have you changed and where was the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You do not call DGEMM correctly.  All of your arguments are `real*8` but many of them are supposed to be `integer`s.

Check thoroughly the documentation of DGEMM  and check your call argument after argument to follow the interface exactly. I am pretty convinced passing the value of 1 instead of the `sizea` for `K` is wrong as well. But really, you have to check each and every argument.

I suggest to test your subroutines in pure Fortran and only after they work correctly use them from Matlab.

Comment: I said check the documentation **thoroughly** argument after argument. Did you do that so quickly or did you just changed `real*8` to `integer` and thought that would suffice? Of course it will not suffice! Show some effort of your own.

Comment: And test the call in pure Fortran too. Enable all error checking features that your compiler has.

Comment: i've read the documentation thoroughly and checked many ways to define function before posting the question, and i forgot to change the variable type to integer
the function works fine in pure fortran and there are no errors

Comment: So, have you actually noticed that I added something to my answer? Is that correct or wrong?

Comment: and its not my first time that i'm using mex files
all my codes are written in pure fortran and then are converted to mex files, and after a long search over the internet and finding nothing, i've asked this question

Comment: i cant understand why that could be a problem.
i think its okay as long as i pass a vector as a second argument

Comment: Because the documentation clearly states that: *"On entry,  K  specifies  the **number of columns of the matrix op( A )** and the number of rows of the matrix op( B )."* That's why I requested that you go through the documentation and check the arguments.

Comment: i'm really sorry, but i've uploaded an old version of my code and i wasn't aware of that since now.
i've updated the code.
no need to tell that the problem is still on